# Windows splash screen, can I post a message?

Tags: windows

I have a set of Windows 10 computers that need to be patched when nobody is using them, and (of course) unused while they are being patched.  I do the patching remotely, so I'm not sitting at the computer ... or even in the same room sometimes.

So ... Is there an easy way that I can programatically (I use `ansible` but I'm open to other ideas) change the default Windows splash or login screen to something with a "DO NOT USE THIS MACHINE" message?  ... or add a message to the default Windows splash or login screen?  (And then, of course, set it back to the default when I'm finished)

Thanks.